# sendfax php not working, gives code 255

Tags: php, centos, asterisk

I am trying to fax out using sendfax but it wont work, when I echo my exec statement it works fine...what's my execution issue?

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", $_REQUEST['Email']);

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $body);
fclose($handle);


exec('sendfax -n -d $to $tmpfname', $test2, $test3);
var_dump($test2);
echo $test3;
?>
```

and I get the response on the page as:

```
array(0) { } 255
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `'single quote strings'` which [do not have variable values interpolated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Try replacing:

```
exec('sendfax -n -d $to $tmpfname', $test2, $test3);
```

with:

```
exec("sendfax -n -d $to $tmpfname", $test2, $test3);
```

Also, you must be *certain* that neither `$to` nor `$tmpfname` contain any shell meta-characters. As it stands, an email address of `foo;rm -rf /&@example.com` would probably delete some files you care about. (I think using `$_REQUEST['Email']` as part of a filename is a bad idea.)

Be sure to read the [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) at the PHP `exec()` documentation page.

Comment: Thanks @hakre -- I'm an old-school type and would much rather use an API that exposes `exec()`'s arguments as an _array_, identical to the C API, so that mistakes would be impossible to make. Alas, PHP's style is "escaping"...

Comment: create a wrapper function that does this :)